# No Fragment.java file created when add new Fragment (Blank) in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using the latest Android Studio.  When creating a new Fragment (New... > Fragment > Fragment), it should create new YourFragment.java and fragment_your.xml files in the project.  When I do this with a ListFragment, it works fine.  But when using the default blank fragment, it creates the appropriate .xml file, but it does not create the Fragment.java file.  No errors are thrown, it simply creates a .xml file.

Comment: Why down voting a good question?

Comment: I think because it's a known bug.  However, given that despite my google-fu, I was unable to find said bug, I personally think it's a valuable question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69078 and will be fixed in the next release.